# How to redirect to previous page in admin?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, url, redirect

In my admin controller action I want to redirect to the previous page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

it does a little more than redirect to the previous page. 
If you specify in the url a parameter `uenc` it will consider that as the referrer.

Comment: Thanks it worked properly as I expected. And I went through the function where located in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`. I think Mahmood Rehman's answer contains the development which has been done through this `_redirectReferer()` function.

Answer (score 9):

Try this code :

```
 Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. When you go through the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class you can find the `_redirectReferer()` function which has developed similar way as your answer. Thanks and +1